# how to change image of moving ccsprite using timer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I have around 10 sprite of same image and these are moving, i want to change the image(2 images) of all sprite alternatively by using timer.
I am using following code but its not working for me

```
  CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"images1.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 140)];
  // Determine where to spawn the target along the Y axis

winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
int minY = target.contentSize.height/2;
int maxY = (winSize.height/2) - target.contentSize.height/2;
int rangeY = maxY - minY;
int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) ;

// Create the target slightly off-screen along the right edge,
// and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above

target.position = ccp(winSize.width + (target.contentSize.width/2), actualY);
[self addChild:target];

// Determine speed of the target

int minDuration = 2.0;
int maxDuration = 4.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;


id delayTime1 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.0f];
id calFun1   = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    //HERE SET BLUE TEXTURE..
    [target setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"image1.png"]texture]];

}];
id delayTime2 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.0f];
id calFun2   = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    //HERE SET RED TEXTURE..
  [target setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"image2.png"]texture]];

}];

// Create the actions

id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration*2.5 position:ccp(-target.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
id sequece = [CCSequence actions:delayTime1, calFun1, delayTime2, calFun2,actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil];
id repeate = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequece];

[target runAction:repeate];
```

But by using this code only one image is continuously showing on sprite. The image is not changing.

Comment: you have to make spritesheet for changing image continuously

Comment: i want to have this functionality without using sprite sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
-(CCSpriteFrame *)getImageWithName:(NSString *)image{
     CCSprite *sprite=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:image];
     CCSpriteFrame *frame=[CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:sprite.texture rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sprite.contentSize.width, sprite.contentSize.height)];
     return frame;
 }
```

Then

```
[target setDisplayFrame:[self getImageWithName:@"image1"]];

[target setDisplayFrame:[self getImageWithName:@"image2"]];
```